# How do I only generate x amount of html elements at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

So I have this ASP.NET Page with a Database hooked up to it.
In this database I have 100 dummy users.

I want to generate two html elements (`<div/>`) at a time so it doesn't fill up the html document.

This is what I have so far

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.UserList.Count; i += 2)
            {
                var displayUsers = Model.UserList.Skip(i).Take(2);

                foreach (var user in displayUsers)
                {
                    <div class="card-item"></div>
                }

            }
```

As you can see it generate two at a time but there is nothing stopping it.
This would keep generating those `<div/>` tags until it's at the end of the list.
I want to be able to have a simple button that I click that removes one while clicking and then one more when I click again and once those are gone it gets the next two from the list.

However I have no idea how I should go on about this, creating a button that removes the element and then has some sort of flag that says okay bring in the next two ones.

What approch should I use to tackle this problem?

Comment: Hi Mark, I am not clear about your question. Are you want to remove dummy/empty value from the list while clicking a button?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JS for this. Razor is executed on the server.